# Windows paging file size

Tags: windows-vista, paging, virtual-memory

I am trying to understand how to set the paging file size appropriately on Vista. For example, under System Properties, Advanced, Performance options it shows under "Total paging file size for all drives", a recommended size of about 8 GB, and a currently allocated of about 4 GB. I've been trying everything possible to (unchecking the box for automatically manage paging file size for all drives) get the value to recommended in order to run some larger problems with my code.

But it only shows briefly (when I use a custom size setting on one of my other hard drives in the computer) after I hit Set and OK; but when I restart it goes back to the default settings?? What am I doing wrong? Appreciate if somebody can point me to some place for help with this or share their experience.

Answer (score 1):

You can alternatively make the change in the registry.

Key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory management`

Value: `PagingFiles`

This value will have an entry for each drive with it's associated pagefile location and its minimum and maximum sizes.

It might look something like this:

`C:\pagefile.sys 250 500`

Where 250 is the minimum and 500 is the maximum. Try changing it in here and see what happens.

Comment: This answer was correct in the past. But sadly this information is not anymore available on Windows 10. There is only the filename but no more sizes.